# Need help converting a UTC date string in Java

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, datetime, jodatime

I have a game client an [Google App Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine) server.  My server sends the client a [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) timedate string which is milliseconds since epoch that represents the datestamp of the last play.  I want my client to report how many days/hours/min since the last play.  I have this working in my iOS client but can't get it to work in Android.  I've tried many options, some using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) some Date objects that are straight Java, the time is always offset by a couple hours.  What's odd is the time is off not on the hour.. could be off 2 hours 34 min.. so I don't think my issue is just a timezone thing or it would be on the hour no?

Essentially I need to get this UTC time and then get the current time in UTC as well.. compare the difference to get days/hours/min

Here's what I have, I'm using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library:

For example my server sends me this string "1392392591.0" (happens to be utc time for approx 7:45am PST)

```
public String convertDateString ( String date ) {

        Float gameEpoch = Float.parseFloat( date ); 

        DateTime now = new DateTime();
        DateTime gameTime = new DateTime(gameEpoch.longValue() * 1000 );

        Period p = new Period(gameTime, now, PeriodType.dayTime());

        String dateString = "";
        if(p.getDays() > 0)
            dateString =  (p.getDays() + " days " + p.getHours() + " hours ago");
        else if(p.getHours() > 0)
            dateString =  (p.getHours() + " hours " + p.getMinutes() + " minutes ago");
        else if(p.getMinutes() > 0)
            dateString =  (p.getMinutes() + " minutes ago");
        else
            dateString = "Just Now";

        return dateString;
    }
```

Comment: `My server sends the client a UTC timedate string which is milliseconds since epoch`. Nope. Your client is receiving *seconds* since the Unix [epoch][1], not *milliseconds*. Obviously you know this and must have mistyped, as your example code is correctly multiplying by 1000. I'm making this note for other readers.

Comment: I suggest adding an `L` to that `1000` to be `1000L`. That's a good habit when doing math with the "long" primitive type to avoid data loss. Adding an `L` also helps to make the code self-documenting, a reminder that we are dealing with longs rather than the more common ints.

Comment: will do, thanks Basil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't convert from a `String` to a `Float`. Floats only have 7 significant digits, hence `gameEpoch` will always be imprecise. Use a `double`, or better yet, a `long`.

Comment: I've adjusted my code and still getting about a 2hr 2min diff from what I'd expect to see (i have a javascript and objectiveC client doing the same thing and they are working).  Here's an update where I convert to Long:  `long gameEpoch = Long.parseLong( date ); `  Interestingly.. if I just check the "now" time in UTC it's off by a few hours from my laptop clock which is to be expected but it's also off by 2min, which I didn't expect.  Should I expect when converting form local time to UTC that more then just the days hours change.. would the min change as well? I wouldn't have thought so

Comment: AH! Found where I was getting thrown.  I'm running this in an android simulator.. turns out the simulator clock was off by 2min and the timezone was set to GMT.  That was throwing me off.  I thing the code above with the Long adjustment is working.  Thanks for the help.. I feel dumb.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Tony the Pony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21784933/642706) is correct.

By the way, in the last half of your example code, you are working too hard. [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) offers a [PeriodFormatterBuilder](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html) class to help you generate those descriptive strings.

This example code needs some finessing, but will get you headed in the right direction.

```
// Period(int years, int months, int weeks, int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int millis)
Period period = new Period( 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0 );

PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .printZeroAlways()
        .appendYears()
        .appendSuffix( " year", " years" )
        .appendSeparator( ", " )
        .printZeroRarelyLast()
        .appendMonths()
        .appendSuffix( " month", " months" )
        .appendSeparator( ", " )
        .appendWeeks()
        .appendSuffix( " week", " weeks" )
        .appendSeparator( ", " )
        .appendDays()
        .appendSuffix( " day", " days" )
        .appendSeparator( ", " )
        .appendHours()
        .appendSuffix( " hour", " hours" )
        .appendSeparator( ", and " )
        .appendMinutes()
        .appendSuffix( " minute", " minutes" )
        .toFormatter();

String timeSpanDescription = formatter.print( period );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "period: " + period );
System.out.println( "timeSpanDescription: " + timeSpanDescription );
```

When run…

```
period: P2DT3H4M
timeSpanDescription: 0 years, 2 days, 3 hours, and 4 minutes
```

Comment: Thanks for the example!  I've refined what I have since posting this.. but I wasn't leveraging the PeriodFormatterBuilder.